# Android TV Emulator Play Store Login

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, television

I'm trying to get the Google Play Store up and running on the Android Studio Emulator for Android TV. Virtual Devices with pre-installed Play Store do exist for Phones, sadly there is no Android TV Image with Play Store included.

Setup:
Android Studio, Android TV with Android 7.0 virtual device, Google Play Services, Android 7.0 SDK, Play Store APK installed from from [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store-android-tv/)

I am able to successfully add a Google account by opening Play Store and loggin in. The Play Store afterwards closes, the account is added to the accounts section in the settings menu. When restarting Play Store the account is still logged out. After trying to login again I get this message: "This account already exists on this device". Removing and re-adding the account from settings menu results in the same problem.

Seems to be a problem with Google Play Services? Any suggestions?

**Screenshots:**

[image: Play Store]
[image: Settings]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am facing a similar dilemma

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2020** :

Now there's official Android TV emulator with Google Play support https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/6-new-ways-to-engage-with-users-on.html